# System load on core dump of multithreaded program

Tags: linux, multithreading, coredump

If a program with a large memory footprint dumps core, it takes a while and runs at 100% cpu.  If I'm running a multithreaded program with real time priority and it dumps core, will it use up all the cores on the box with real time priority starving everything else for a while? If so, is there a way to make the core dumping only use one cpu without pinning the process itself to doing so?

Comment: How is the core dump being triggered? Is this just a segfault triggering a core dump automatically? Or are you triggering it in some specific way? (One workaround is to catch `SIGILL`, `SIGBUS`, and `SIGSEGV`. In the handler, switch out of real time priority, remove the signal handlers, and then dereference a NULL pointer to force a core dump.)

Comment: Yes, coming from a segfault.  I already catch `SIGSEGV`, etc. to do some emergency clean up, reset the sigaction, and reraise to dump core. There's no reason not to add changing the priority to the handler.

Comment: If it helps, I've also observed the problem that dumping core can be unusually expensive on Linux and can freeze (or at least slow) a system for a surprisingly long time, even if there weren't obvious explanations such as the process being too large to fit entirely in RAM. I never found a workaround or explanation.